# Where to put an "Activity Log" affordance on a page with fairly high info density?

Tags: buttons, enterprise, activity-feed, tab

[image: Rule Builder page]

Hey!

I'm designing a rule builder tool and trying to figure out where to put an "Activity Log" affordance - basically a place where the user can click and see a complete list of the edits that have been made to a specific rule, as well as their timestamps.

Right now it's located in the "Queue" button (see screenshot), which, when clicked, displays a modal list of all the changes to the rule. However, this doesn't seem right, because the rest of those CTA's on the top right are reserved for explicit actions, not necessarily "locations" where the user will be taken.

So I'm wondering where else this affordance can be on the page where it makes sense in terms of UI best practices + principles? It doesn't really matter if it opens up in a modal or another page.

Also, making it a third tab next to "Live" and "Draft" is not workable because, prior to making a draft, there's a little "+ Create Draft" button next to the "Live" tab, which creates the Draft tab - so squeezing the Activity Log in there with that interaction happening is kinda tricky.

Anyways, I hope that all makes sense. Thanks for taking a look! Looking forward to your input :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well the question, what you are trying to do is showing a history of the changes made.

I don't think the location is wrong, maybe to differentiate an immediate actions CTA to another type of button, a shape contrast is enough.

[image]

Comment: That's a great idea, @Danielillo! Thanks for the input